# IF Row color Changes from Purple to White Default Color then write

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using below Script which i want to work like whenever Sheet row Color changes from `Purple` to `White Default Color` then it should write `Date` and `time` to `column L`.

But it is not working accordingly. It should not write Date to `column L` when cell is being edited row is being added. It should work just when Row color is change from `Purple` to `White Default Color`

Any help will be appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j9CzSkvZDcHTDFfCb4LxZ-gT4PLAiKOifi3NsWZJu3U/edit#gid=0

```
function colorChangeCheck() { 
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var color = sh.getActiveRange().getBackground();
  var row = sh.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var col = sh.getActiveRange().getColumn();

  if(color == "#ead1dc" || color == "#ffffff"){ //Do nothing if the default color is #ead1dc (Purple) OR #ffffff (White)
    return;
  }else{
    if(sh.getRange(row, col+1).getBackground() == "#ffffff" && sh.getRange(row, col-1).getBackground() == "#ffffff"){ //Disregard if the row being changed is in white color
      return;
    }else{
      sh.getRange("L"+sh.getActiveRange().getRow()).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Log the colors.

Comment: Sorry i do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your function is bound to an `onEdit` trigger, what you need instead is an `onChange` trigger

- `onEdit` fires when the cell contents are edited, not the formatting
- Change in formatting will be reflected in the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) of an `onChange` trigger
- The information contained in this event object in case of a color change taking place will look like the following:

`{"authMode":"FULL","changeType":"FORMAT","source":{},"triggerUid":"8885684","user":{"email":"XXX","nickname":"XXX"}}`

What you can do:

- First, change the type of your trigger from `onEdit` to `onChange`:

[image]

- Then, you can modify your code as following to perform an action only when the change event was a format change and when the new color of the range is white:

```
function colorChangeCheck(e) { 
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var color = sh.getActiveRange().getBackground();
  if(e.changeType == "FORMAT" && color  == "#ffffff"){
    sh.getRange("L"+sh.getActiveRange().getRow()).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
  }
}
```

**Important:**

This snippet does not allow you to know what the previous color was and either the change event was a color change or another formatting change (e.g. making the text bold).

The implementation of this functionality would be much more complicated, since you would need to store the background color of all cells of your sheet within the [script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties), so you can compare the old color to the new color.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the answer. @ziganotschka There are 3 to 4 colors that are used on the sheet. so i want this function to run for specific color that is `Purple`. and i can you please share that how to mention range instead of active range i used this but its not working.  `var color = sh.getRange('C1:C1000').getBackground();` then change this `sh.getRange("L"+sh.getRange('C1:C1000').getRow()).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to run the function when the color changes from white to purple. But unfortunately there is no event listener that allows you to detect this event. It is not the same like when cell content changes from "a" to "b" (which could be detected with `e.Value` and `e.oldValue` of an `enEdit` trigger). So you would need to store the old cell color for all cells manually and compare them to the new color when a formatting event takes place.

Comment: No, I want to run the function when color changes from Purple to white. Your function is working fine as i requested. But if i paste the red color then change it to white it paste the date and time. and  i would appreciated if could write the range as `(C1:C1000)` so it can specify the column not all row.

Comment: I just want to include the specific range that is `B1:J1000` in which if color changes to default then run the code. It should not work in entire sheet. @ziganotschka

Comment: Hello @ShRa. Did you try something yourself to adapt your code to the range `B1:J1000`? Stackoverflow is not a free coding service, but a forum where people give you suggestions with problems you might encounter when trying to implement a functionality yourself. As the function working only when color changes from purple to white, I tried to explain you above why this would be very complicated to implement.